# Distinguish between property is protected and setter is protected

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Is there a way to determine the **setter** visibility difference of:

```
public Prop { get; protected set; }
protected Prop { get; set; }
```

using Reflection? Or are those equivalent in regards to C# Reflection?

Comment: Why would you expect it to be different? Does the setter *behave* differently in any way?

Comment: I'm writing a little assembly inspecting tool, which should accurately display property visibilities.

Comment: Maybe also inspect the *getter* and check *it's* protection level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the two setters are identical.

The definitive way to verify this is to look at the IL generated for the two variants. I compiled a little test with the following two properties:

```
  public    int Prop  { get; protected set; }
  protected int Prop2 { get; set; }
```

And then I disassembled it. The IL is identical for the setters for both properties, save for the difference in their names (`Prop` vs `Prop2`):

```
.method family hidebysig specialname instance void 
        set_Prop(int32 'value') cil managed
{
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       8 (0x8)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldarg.1
  IL_0002:  stfld      int32 ConsoleApplication1.Program::'<Prop>k__BackingField'
  IL_0007:  ret
} // end of method Program::set_Prop
```

```
.method family hidebysig specialname instance void 
        set_Prop2(int32 'value') cil managed
{
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       8 (0x8)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldarg.1
  IL_0002:  stfld      int32 ConsoleApplication1.Program::'<Prop2>k__BackingField'
  IL_0007:  ret
} // end of method Program::set_Prop2
```

If the method were public, it would be annotated with `public` at the top, in the list of [method attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodattributes.aspx) that come after `.method`. Similarly if it were `private`. In this case, both are simply `protected`, which is denoted by `family`.

I would say that this is consistent with expectations: both setters have identical visibilities, so they should appear identical to the compiler and run-time environment.

Comment: Thanks, thought there maybe a compiler-generated attribute with more information, but apparently there is no such thing. Thank you for your effort, accepting as soon as possible!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PropertyInfo.GetSetMethod(true)`. If you get an exception, then that means that a private / protected setter does not exist.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this answers my question. Could you maybe write it down as a `Func<PropertyInfo, int>` which returns `1` for the first property and `2` for the second property? Would be helpful, thanks!